# Add manager to Alfresco share site if there are no managers in the site

Tags: document-management

I setup Alfresco share for a big company. I import the users from AD via ldap. There was a site which had only one manager. The managers user account got deleted from ad and so now there are no managers in the site. Now no one can approve any new managers for the site.

Is there a way we can add a new manager to the site?

(We recreated the user in ad with the same user name, but the new user does not have manager in the site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix it via a manual script you execute as Java Script

```
var site = siteService.getSite("XXXX");
site.setMembership("admin", "SiteManager");
```